# How to categorize data for each date in sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, date-arithmetic

I am using Oracle sql developer.And I have to categorize some data into each `Date` from a table.

I used `TO_CHAR` function to change the date format.

```
select to_char(txn_date, 'dd-mon-rrrr') my_day, some_coloums
from mwt_wallet_transactions 
order by my_day;
```

It's ok with upper one. But I want to get it with given date like this:

```
select to_char( txn_date, 'dd-mon-rrrr') my_day, some_coloums
from mwt_wallet_transactions 
where my_day like '08-feb-2015'
order by my_day;
```

I searched this over the internet, most of them asked to use the `CONVERT` function like this:

```
select convert (VARCHAR(10), txn_date , 23 )  my_day, some_colomns
from mwt_wallet_transactions 
where my_day like '08-feb-2015'
order by my_day;
```

But it doesn't work for me. Help me to solve this!

Comment: ORDER BY before WHERE... Switch place... And you need a derived table.

Comment: What gave you the idea of using `LIKE`? I see this again and again and I always wonder why people use it so frequently when they only want to compare exact values. Is there a reason you didn't use `where my_day = '08-feb-2015'`? Do you expect `LIKE` to do something here that `=` doesn't do?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner "*Is there a reason you didn't use where my_day = '08-feb-2015'*"  But that would compare a date with a string. **DATE** and **STRING** are not same. `'08-feb-2015'` is a string, not a date.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar: First of all `LIKE` is for strings only also, only that it allows for wildchars. Then, both my_day and '08-feb-2015' *are* strings, so what date are you referring to?

Comment: @KDGamage: `CONVERT` is a SQL Server function. It is not as good as Oracle's `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` in my opinion, as it only knows certain formats. SQL Server's `CONVERT` is not available in Oracle.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `LIKE ` and `=` with `'08-feb-2015' are both irrelevant here as we are dealing with `DATE` and not a string.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ok, you are talking about the SELECTED expression `my_day`. My bad, I thought of the column itself which is date data type. In that case, your suggestion won't work becasue you cannot refence a column alias in the predicate, it  must be a static column.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B: I know that it would be best to deal with the original date txn_date and use to_date on the string '08-feb-2015' or even use a date literal, just as you explain in your answer (which is why I upvoted it :-). I know that the OP's query is wrong and I know why it is wrong. I only would like to know what gave 'em the idea of using LIKE here at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> where my_day like '08-feb-2015'

I think you got confused between **SELECTION** and **FILTER PREDICATE**.

Also, remember, `''08-feb-2015'` is NOT a **DATE**, it is a **string**.

You want to filter the rows based on a DATE value. So, convert the literal on the R.H.S. into **DATE** using `TO_DATE` or use **ANSI Date literal** if you don't have a time portion.

Now, remember, a DATE has both date and time elements, so you need to -

- either use `TRUNC` on the date column to get rid off the time element
- or, use a **DATE range condition** to for better **performance** as it would use any **regular index** on the date column.

I am assuming `my_day` as the date column. Modify the filter as:

Using **ANSI Date literal**: fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

```
where my_day >= DATE '2015-02-08' and   my_day < DATE '2015-02-09'
```

Or, `TO_DATE` with proper **format model**. Remember, `TO_DATE` is **NLS dependent**, so I have used `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` to make it NLS independent.

```
WHERE my_day >= TO_DATE('08-feb-2015','dd-mon-yyyy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american') 
AND   my_day < TO_DATE('09-feb-2015','dd-mon-yyyy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=american')
```

Above. `my_day` is assumed as the static date column, and not the column alias.

Comment: I think it's a pity that Oracle calls this type DATE, although it has a time part. DATETIME would have been a more appropriate name, and it would have been great to have an *additional* type DATE for dates without a time part. However, things as they are, but with a column name `txn_date`, I'd expect this to *be* a date, i.e. there is a constraint `txn_date = trunc(txn_date)` or even a corresponding before insert/update trigger on this column. Then a mere `txn_date = date'2015-02-08'` would work just fine.

Comment: Thank you both of you,
@thorstenKettner  , "txn_date = date'2015-02-08'"   is not working.Is that better to use "cast(txn_date as DATE) my_day"  or  "cast(txn_date as VARCHAR) my_day"  ?

Comment: What do you mean with "txn_date = date'2015-02-08' is not working? Are you getting an error or are you getting wrong results? CAST should not be necessary. What data type is txn_date? We supposed it to be DATE and so you should be able to compare with date'2015-02-08', which is February 8, 2015 of course. Do your values for this column contain time parts (i.e. do you get rows when selecting `select * from from mwt_wallet_transactions where txn_date <> trunc(txn_date)`?

Comment: @KDGamage What do you mean by "*not working*", it is not a standard oracle error. What is the error? What is your oracle database version up to 4 decimal places? What are the data types of the columns involved? Edit your question and add these details. We assume your date column is **DATE data type**.

Comment: I meant , while using " txn_date = date '2015-02-08' " with `WHERE` clause it's not gave me result for  mentioned date.  txn_date is in `DATE` format as  `30-JAN-14  12.00.00.000000000 AM` . So i used   `to_char(txn_date, 'dd-mon-rrrr')` to get it as `30-JAN-15` . If  `TO_CHAR` function gives a `String` value,why we can't use it with `LIKE ` operator.

Comment: @KDGamage Look at the answer above, I have provided the WHERE clause using a DATE range condition. I have never said you need to do an equal to. Just copy paste the date range condition and rename the column name as per your column name.

Comment: @KDGamage "*If TO_CHAR function gives a String value,why we can't use it with LIKE operator.*" Why would you unnecessarily convert a date into string and then compare it with a string? Moreover, using to_char on the column won't use any regular index. You should leave the date as it as and use to_date on the literal. And compare it as a date range condition. There is a complete answer above.

Comment: @LalitKumarB , As you mentioned on your answer, I used `TRUNC(txn_date)` , it works well and thanks for that. but results comes as column named with TRUNC(txn_date). How can i assume the name as `my_day` to it?it can't assume  from `AS` statement.

Comment: @LalitKumarB ,Thank for all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95008/discussion-between-kdgamage-and-lalit-kumar-b).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use select list column aliases in the `WHERE` clause. Use derived table to access it:

```
select * from
(
 select *some_computed_value* as my_day, some_colomns
 from mwt_wallet_transaction
) 
where *my_day conditions*
order by my_day
```

Comment: `convert (VARCHAR(10), txn_date , 23 )` isn't valid Oracle syntax. Also, if you're wanting to date comparisons, it helps to keep the dates as DATEs, rather than converting them to strings and then comparing. In general, it's safer, would allow the use of indexes on the DATE column, and just makes more sense.

Comment: It's not? Well, my answer's purpose is to show how to use column aliases in WHERE clause using a derived table. I can remove that part...

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I checked this solutions and it's working well,

```
select * from
(select cast( TRUNC(txn_date) as date) my_day ,some_columns
from mwt_wallet_transactions
)
where my_day = '08-FEB-15'
order by my_day
;
```

or we can use:

```
select * from
(select to_char( txn_date, 'dd-mon-rrrr') my_day 
from mwt_wallet_transactions
)
where my_day = '08-feb-2015'
order by my_day;
```

Comment: It means `txn_date` is stored as **string** and not a **DATE**? And you never told us the data type. And it is a bad design to store dates as strings. This solution might just work for you, but future readers should be warned about the bad design. And that this is just a workaround for your case.